# Improving performance of big EF multi-level Include

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm an EF noob (as in I just started today, I've only used other ORMs), and I'm experiencing a baptism of fire.

I've been asked to improve the performance of this query created by another dev:

```
      var questionnaires = await _myContext.Questionnaires
            .Include("Sections")
            .Include(q => q.QuestionnaireCommonFields)
            .Include("Sections.Questions")
            .Include("Sections.Questions.Answers")
            .Include("Sections.Questions.Answers.AnswerMetadatas")
            .Include("Sections.Questions.Answers.SubQuestions")
            .Include("Sections.Questions.Answers.SubQuestions.Answers")
            .Include("Sections.Questions.Answers.SubQuestions.Answers.AnswerMetadatas")
            .Include("Sections.Questions.Answers.SubQuestions.Answers.SubQuestions")
            .Include("Sections.Questions.Answers.SubQuestions.Answers.SubQuestions.Answers")
            .Include("Sections.Questions.Answers.SubQuestions.Answers.SubQuestions.Answers.AnswerMetadatas")
            .Include("Sections.Questions.Answers.SubQuestions.Answers.SubQuestions.Answers.SubQuestions")
            .Include("Sections.Questions.Answers.SubQuestions.Answers.SubQuestions.Answers.SubQuestions.Answers")
            .Include("Sections.Questions.Answers.SubQuestions.Answers.SubQuestions.Answers.SubQuestions.Answers.AnswerMetadatas")
            .Include("Sections.Questions.Answers.SubQuestions.Answers.SubQuestions.Answers.SubQuestions.Answers.SubQuestions")
            .Include("Sections.Questions.Answers.SubQuestions.Answers.SubQuestions.Answers.SubQuestions.Answers.SubQuestions.Answers")
            .Include("Sections.Questions.Answers.SubQuestions.Answers.SubQuestions.Answers.SubQuestions.Answers.SubQuestions.Answers.AnswerMetadatas")
            .Include("Sections.Questions.Answers.SubQuestions.Answers.SubQuestions.Answers.SubQuestions.Answers.SubQuestions.Answers.SubQuestions")
            .Include("Sections.Questions.Answers.SubQuestions.Answers.SubQuestions.Answers.SubQuestions.Answers.SubQuestions.Answers.SubQuestions.Answers")
            .Include("Sections.Questions.Answers.SubQuestions.Answers.SubQuestions.Answers.SubQuestions.Answers.SubQuestions.Answers.SubQuestions.Answers.AnswerMetadatas")
        .Where(q => questionnaireIds.Contains(q.Id))
        .ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

A quick web-surf tells me that Include() results in a cols * rows product and poor performance if you run multiple levels deep.

I've seen some helpful answers on SO, but they have limited less complex examples, and I can't figure out the best approach for a rewrite of the above.

The multiple repeat of the part -"Sections.Questions.Answers.SubQuestions.Answers.SubQuestions.Answers..." looks suspicious to me like it could be done separately and then another query issued, but I don't know how to build this up or whether such an approach would even improve performance.

Questions:

1. How do I rewrite this query to something more sensible to improve performance, while ensuring that the eventual result set is the same?
2. Given the last line: `.Include("Sections.Questions.Answers.SubQuestions.Answers.SubQuestions.Answers.SubQuestions.Answers.SubQuestions.Answers.SubQuestions.Answers.AnswerMetadatas")`
   Why do I need all the intermediate lines? (I guess it's because some of the joins may not be left joins?)

EF Version info: package id="EntityFramework" version="6.2.0" targetFramework="net452"

I realise this question is a bit rubbish, but I'm trying to resolve as fast as I can from a point of no knowledge.

> **Edit**

After mulling over this for half a day and thanks to StuartLC's suggestions I came up with some options:

Poor - split the query so that it performs multiple round-trips to fetch the data. This is likely to provide a slightly slower experience for the user, but will stop the SQL timing out. (This is not much better than just increasing the EF command timeout).

Good - change the clustered indexing on child tables to be clustered by their parent's foreign key (assuming you don't have a lot of insert operations).

Good - change the code to only query the first few levels and lazy-load (separate db hit) anything below this, i.e. remove all but the top few Includes, then change the ICollections - Answers.SubQuestions, Answers.AnswerMetadatas, and Question.Answers to all be virtual. Presumably the downside to making these virtual is that if any (other) existing code in the app expects those ICollection properties to be eager-loaded, you may have to update that code (i.e. if you want/need them to load immediately within that code). I will be investigating this option further. Further edit - unfortunately this won't work if you need to serialize the response due to self-referencing loop.

Non-trivial - Write a sql stored proc/view manually and build a new EF object pointed at it.

**Longer term**

The obvious, best, but most time-consuming option - rewrite the app design, so it doesn't need the whole data tree in a single api call, or go with the option below:

Rewrite the app to store the data in a NoSQL fashion (e.g. store the object tree as json so there are no joins). As Stuart mentioned this is not a good option if you need to filter the data in other ways (via something other than the questionnaireId), which you might need to do. Another alternative is to partially store NoSQL-style and partially relational as required.

Comment: Have a look at https://entityframework.net/improve-ef-include-performance

Comment: @immirza - thanks, though i don't understand that code because he reuses "var customers", which would be a compilation error?

Comment: No, compiler automatically determine the type. An example, var i = 10; and int i = 10; are functionally equivalent.

Comment: @immirza what i mean is - he declares the same variable several times, i.e. var customers = ... var customers =... var customers = ...    I guess the var shouldn't be there after the first one. I'll give it a go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First up, it must be said that this isn't a trivial query. Seemingly we have:

- 6 levels of recursion through a nested question-answer tree
- A total of 20 tables are joined in this way via eager loaded `.Include`

I would first take the time to determine where this query is used in your app, and how often it is needed, with particular attention to where it is used most frequently.

**YAGNI optimizations**

The obvious place to start is to see where the query is used in your app, and if you don't need the whole tree all the time, then suggest you don't join in the nested question and answer tables if they are not needed in all usages of the query.

Also, it is possible to compose on `IQueryable` dynamically, so if there are multiple use cases for your query (e.g. from a "Summary" screen which doesn't need the question + answers, and a details tree which does need them), then you can do something like:

```
var questionnaireQuery = _myContext.Questionnaires
        .Include(q => q.Sections)
        .Include(q => q.QuestionnaireCommonFields);

// Conditionally extend the joins
if (mustIncludeQandA)
{
     questionnaireQuery = questionnaireQuery
       .Include(q => q.Sections.Select(s => s.Questions.Select(q => q.Answers..... etc);
}

// Execute + materialize the query
var questionnaires = await questionnaireQuery
    .Where(q => questionnaireIds.Contains(q.Id))
    .ToListAsync()
    .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

**SQL Optimizations**

If you really have to fetch the whole tree all the time, then look at your SQL table design and indexing.

1) Filters

```
.Where(q => questionnaireIds.Contains(q.Id))
```

(I'm assuming SQL Server terminology here, but the concepts are applicable in most other RDBMs as well.)

I'm guessing `Questionnaires.Id` is a clustered primary key, so will be indexed, but just check for sanity (it will look something `PK_Questionnaires CLUSTERED UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY` in SSMS)

2) Ensure all child tables have indexes on their foreign keys back to the parent.

e.g. `q => q.Sections` means that table `Sections` has a foreign key back to `Questionnaires.Id` - make sure this has at least a non-clustered index on it - EF Code First should do this automagically, but again, check to be sure.

This would look like `IX_QuestionairreId NONCLUSTERED` on column `Sections(QuestionairreId)`

3) Consider changing the clustered indexing on child tables to be clustered by their parent's foreign key, e.g. Cluster `Section` by `Questions.SectionId`. This will keep all child rows related to the same parent together, and reduce the number of pages of data that SQL needs to fetch. [It isn't trivial](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33765908/314291) to achieve in EF code first, but your DBA can assist you in doing this, perhaps as a custom step.

**Other comments**

If this query is only used to query data, not to update or delete, then adding `.AsNoTracking()` will marginally reduce the memory consumption and in-memory performance of EF.

Unrelated to performance, but you've mixed the weakly typed ("Sections") and strongly typed `.Include` statements (`q => q.QuestionnaireCommonFields`). I would suggest moving to the strongly typed includes for the additional compile time safety.

Note that you only need to specify the include path for the longest chain(s) which are eager loaded - this will obviously force EF to include all higher levels too. i.e. You can reduce the 20 `.Include` statements to just 2. This will do the same job more efficiently:

```
.Include(q => q.QuestionnaireCommonFields)
.Include(q => q.Sections.Select(s => s.Questions.Select(q => q.Answers .... etc))
```

You'll need `.Select` any time there is a 1:Many relationship, but if the navigation is 1:1 (or N:1) then you don't need the .Select, e.g. `City c => c.Country`

**Redesign**

Last but not least, if data is only ever filtered from the top level (i.e. `Questionnaires`), and if the whole questionairre 'tree' (Aggregate Root) is typically always added or updated all at once, then you might try and approach the data modelling of the question and answer tree in a `NoSQL` way, e.g. by simply modelling the whole tree as XML or JSON, and then treat the whole tree as a long string. This will avoid all the nasty joins altogether. You would need a custom deserialization step in your data tier. This latter approach won't be very useful if you need to filter from nodes in the tree (i.e. a Query like *find me all questionairre's where the SubAnswer to Question 5 is "Foo"* won't be a good fit)

Comment: Many thanks for your detailed answer, it confirmed many of my ignorant theories. Unfortunately the (current) app design requires the whole tree. I've checked the indexes as you suggested, they look right. Re: "You can reduce the 20 .Include statements to just 2." - this is a big one for me, so thanks for specifically addressing that part of my question.

Comment: @jimasp Though we probably haven't miraculously made things 10 times faster, either :(. I'm guessing there's a lot of data in the lower `SubQuestions` and `Answers` tables. Old school, but if you don't need 90% of the data online, you might consider archiving old data, or splitting / sharding into separate "RecentData" and "ArchivedData" databases, at least to get the performance of the recent data improved.

Comment: I'm thinking the best short-term solution might actually be to manually write a SQL view and see how that performs, then get EF to query that. Though I don't know if there are any in-memory EF model synchronisation concerns there.
(Also your suggestion about FK clustered index is something I will look into).